# Nginx Reverse Proxy Segfault on High Traffic

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, syslog, dmesg

Recently my load balancer with Nginx rev proxy showing the following error messages on /var/log/dmesg:

```
[6278902.558300] nginx[15683]: segfault at ffffffffffffffff ip 0000000000457b99 sp 00007fffca4b8f20 error 4 in nginx[400000+ce000]
[6278903.937915] nginx[15681]: segfault at ffffffffffffffff ip 0000000000457b99 sp 00007fffca4b8fa0 error 4 in nginx[400000+ce000]
[6278908.126182] nginx[15685]: segfault at ffffffffffffffff ip 0000000000457b99 sp 00007fffca4b8f20 error 4 in nginx[400000+ce000]
[6278909.428301] nginx[15679]: segfault at ffffffffffffffff ip 0000000000457b99 sp 00007fffca4b8f20 error 4 in nginx[400000+ce000]
[6278911.413366] nginx[15691]: segfault at ffffffffffffffff ip 0000000000457b99 sp 00007fffca4b8f20 error 4 in nginx[400000+ce000]
[6278915.461372] nginx[15630]: segfault at ffffffffffffffff ip 0000000000457b99 sp 00007fffca4b8f20 error 4 in nginx[400000+ce000]
[6278928.510734] nginx[15695]: segfault at ffffffffffffffff ip 0000000000457b99 sp 00007fffca4b8fa0 error 4 in nginx[400000+ce000]
[6278928.591095] nginx[15608]: segfault at ffffffffffffffff ip 0000000000457b99 sp 00007fffca4b8fa0 error 4 in nginx[400000+ce000]
[6278941.815013] nginx[15689]: segfault at ffffffffffffffff ip 0000000000457b99 sp 00007fffca4b8f20 error 4 in nginx[400000+ce000]
```

And on /var/log/syslog:

```
Jun 24 14:16:05 koopa kernel: [6278903.937915] nginx[15681]: segfault at ffffffffffffffff ip 0000000000457b99 sp 00007fffca4b8fa0 error 4 in nginx[400000+ce000]
Jun 24 14:16:09 koopa kernel: [6278908.126182] nginx[15685]: segfault at ffffffffffffffff ip 0000000000457b99 sp 00007fffca4b8f20 error 4 in nginx[400000+ce000]
Jun 24 14:16:10 koopa kernel: [6278909.428301] nginx[15679]: segfault at ffffffffffffffff ip 0000000000457b99 sp 00007fffca4b8f20 error 4 in nginx[400000+ce000]
Jun 24 14:16:12 koopa kernel: [6278911.413366] nginx[15691]: segfault at ffffffffffffffff ip 0000000000457b99 sp 00007fffca4b8f20 error 4 in nginx[400000+ce000]
Jun 24 14:16:16 koopa kernel: [6278915.461372] nginx[15630]: segfault at ffffffffffffffff ip 0000000000457b99 sp 00007fffca4b8f20 error 4 in nginx[400000+ce000]
Jun 24 14:16:29 koopa kernel: [6278928.510734] nginx[15695]: segfault at ffffffffffffffff ip 0000000000457b99 sp 00007fffca4b8fa0 error 4 in nginx[400000+ce000]
Jun 24 14:16:29 koopa kernel: [6278928.591095] nginx[15608]: segfault at ffffffffffffffff ip 0000000000457b99 sp 00007fffca4b8fa0 error 4 in nginx[400000+ce000]
Jun 24 14:16:43 koopa kernel: [6278941.815013] nginx[15689]: segfault at ffffffffffffffff ip 0000000000457b99 sp 00007fffca4b8f20 error 4 in nginx[400000+ce000]
Jun 24 14:16:56 koopa kernel: [6278955.124605] nginx[15693]: segfault at ffffffffffffffff ip 0000000000457b99 sp 00007fffca4b8fa0 error 4 in nginx[400000+ce000]
```

other info:

```
$ nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.4.7

$ uname -a
Linux koopa 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

No more information i can squeeze from the server logs, sometimes the server was down for 1-2 mins everyday.

Does anyone have experience such issues ?
Any idea what ip is this `0000000000457b99`

Fyi, i'm not comfortable to do debugging since this is a production server.

Let me know if you guys need more information regarding my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: the ip (0000000000457b99) is not an actual IP adress. Also, I would advise you to [fill a bug report](http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/)

Comment: Ok, could be something with the redirection, because it's failed to do redirection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not IP as in IP address, but IP as in instruction pointer.

You've encountered a bug in nginx.  Consider upgrading, if you are running an outdated version.  You could also file a bug report if you can tell what happened immediately before the segfault (check the rest of the log) or have a coredump (as long as there is nothing confidential on the server).

Comment: It's no longer the latest nginx, currently by today the latest nginx ver is 1.6.0. I will try to do coredump. thanks